# Showing $5^{1/3}$ is not in the field $\mathbb{Q}(2^{1/3})$

Tags: abstract-algebra, extension-field

I want to show $5^{1/3}$ is not in the field $\mathbb{Q}(2^{1/3})$. My reasoning was $[\mathbb{Q}(2^{1/3}):\mathbb{Q}]=3$ and $[\mathbb{Q}(5^{1/3}):\mathbb{Q}]=3$. Similarly we know that  $[\mathbb{Q}(2^{1/3}, 5^{1/3}):\mathbb{Q}]=9$ so by multiplicativity of dimensions, $[\mathbb{Q}(5^{1/3}):\mathbb{Q(2^{1/3})}]=3$ which implies that $5^{1/3} \not\in \mathbb{Q}(2^{1/3})$. Is this the right approach?

Comment: You meant you want to show that $5^{1/3}$ is *not* in $\Bbb Q(2^{1/3})$, right?

Comment: How do you *know* that the dimension of $\mathbb{Q}(2^{1/3},5^{1/3})$ over the rationals is $9$?

Comment: It is a right approach if you succeed in proving the dimension assertion. But I would choose crude and direct.

Comment: What do you mean crude and direct,? @AndréNicolas

Comment: Suppose to the contrary that $5^{1/3}=a+b\cdot2^{1/3}+c\cdot2^{2/3}$ where $a,b,c$ are rational.

Comment: Oh, I see, yeah I thought about it but I would have had to raise the whole thing to power of 3 which would end up being long, I was seeing if I could avoid it.

Answer (score 1):

What you wrote works as an outline, but I think your claims about the degree of each field extension would need explanation.

---

For $[\mathbb{Q}(2^{1/3}):\mathbb{Q}]$ and $[\mathbb{Q}(5^{1/3}):\mathbb{Q}]$ you need to show that the irreducible polynomials of $2^{1/3}$ and  $5^{1/3}$ over $\Bbb Q$ have degree 3.

(Since you know that $2^{1/3}$ is a root of $x^3-2 \in \Bbb Q[x]$, you just need to explain why $x^3-2$ is irreducible over $\Bbb Q$. You can use Eisenstein's criterion. Same for $5^{1/3}$.)

---

The more difficult part is explaining why $[\mathbb{Q}(2^{1/3}, 5^{1/3}):\mathbb{Q}]=9$.

I think I'd write the extensions in a different way and then use the multiplicative property of the degree:

$\Bbb Q \subseteq \Bbb Q(2^{1/3}) \subseteq [\Bbb Q(2^{1/3})](5^{1/3})=\mathbb{Q}(2^{1/3}, 5^{1/3})$, so the problem becomes showing that $5^{1/3}$ has degree $3$ over $\Bbb Q(2^{1/3})$.

$[\Bbb Q(2^{1/3}):\Bbb Q]=3$, so $\Bbb Q(2^{1/3})$ has a basis of three elements: $1, 2^{1/3}$ and $2^{2/3}$.

You can use this to show that $5^{1/3}$ is not an element of $\Bbb Q(2^{1/3})$: you could try writing it as a linear combination of the basis elements with coefficients in $\Bbb Q$ and deriving a contradiction. (This might be long and tedious.)

Comment: Thanks for explaining! Yeah, i will write more details next time.

Comment: You're welcome :)

Comment: While I think degrees of field extensions could be helpful for the OP question, I note that your last two paragraphs stand completely on their own as a proof strategy, without needing any of the stuff above it.

Comment: @GregMartin interesting... I guess I was more trying to show how I thought each of the claims OP made could be justified than to write a nice cohesive proof :P. I think from the first part it's still necessary to explain the degree of $2^{1/3}$ over $\Bbb Q$ using the irreducible polynomial, no? Explaining that part shows an awareness of Eisenstein.

Comment: It's true that one needs to justify why $\{1,2^{1/3},2^{2/3}\}$ is a $\Bbb Q$-basis for $\Bbb Q(2^{1/3})$. Although for extensions generated by a root of an integer, that's pretty easy to see by hand.

Answer (score 0):

In general, if $p$ and $q$ are two different primes and $k>1$, $p^{1/k}\not\in\mathbb{Q}(q^{1/k})$.

Assuming the opposite, for any sufficiently big prime number $r\equiv 1\pmod{k}$, with $q$ being a $k$-th residue $\pmod{r}$, $p$ would be a $k$-th residue, too, but we may provide counter-examples to that situation through the Chinese theorem.

Comment: Why would $p$ be a $k$th residue in that situation?

Comment: @GregMartin: because we assumed $p^{1/k}\in\mathbb{Q}(q^(1/k))$, hence if $q^{1/k}$ lives in $\mathbb{F}_r^*$ and not in some extension, $p^{1/k}$ lives in $\mathbb{F}_r^*$, too.

Comment: This should also work for $p^{1/k_1}\notin\mathbb Q(q^{1/k_2})$.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio Can you please tell me what is the definition of a $k$-th residue, that is, given integers $r$ and $k$, when do we say that an integer $q$ is a $k$-th residue of mod $r$? Thank you.

Comment: @caffeinemachine: we say that $a$ is a $k$-th residue $\!\!\pmod{p}$ if $a\equiv b^k\pmod{p}$ for some $b$.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio Can you please elaborate on how we are applying the Chinese remainder theorem to get a contradiction? Thank you.